# How do I monitor processes/apps or file locks on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, process, filesystems, monitoring

I'm porting a file encryption app from Windows to Mac OSX. One of its features, is that it lets you open an encrypted file in its source application (say TextEdit), make some changes and then re-rencrypt the file.

To accomplish this on OSX, I would like to either monitor the start/stop of the process that is launched when I ask the system to open my decrypted document, or monitor the file itself for any acquired and released locks.

Is there a way to programatically accomplish this, either through existing OSX or Unix APIs? I've already tried the .NET provided APIs (FileSystemWatcher, Process) without luck.

Comment: You normally should be watching the application that you've launched to see when it closes.  If it closes you can assume the file lock has been released.  However, I'm certain that somebody else will be able to provide you with a method of checking fs locks.  Try checking out some of the CLI utils that are bundled with unix like systems PS and a few others are universally bundled and are able to indicate file locks quite nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing, was to listen to Notifications from `NSNotificationCenter` and `NSApplication` after I had asked the OS to open my file in its default Application. The particular events were:

- `NSWorkspace.Notifications.ObserveDidLaunchApplication(EventHandler)`
- `NSWorkspace.Notifications.ObserveDidTerminateApplication(EventHandler)`

If you're stuck with the same issue, please [see my implementation here](https://bitbucket.org/slamti/axcrypt-net/src/0ce01606a8ed/Axantum.AxCrypt.Core.MacOsx/Launcher.cs?at=default).